# Colon character is messing up my pattern match in Bash

Tags: bash, wildcards

I have a variable `$line`, which can contain any of the following strings:

- `line="READ CACHE IS: ENABLED"`
- `line="BLOCKS READ CACHE AND SENT TO INITIATOR = 2489338280"`
- `line="ECC REREADS/ ERRORS ALGORITHM PROCESSED UNCORRECTED"`
- `line="READ: 2513550726 22 0 2513550748 2513550748 27768.965 0"`
- `line="1 RAW_READ_ERROR_RATE PO-R-- 100 100 016 - 0"`
- `line="0x22 GPL R/O 1 READ STREAM ERROR LOG"`
- `line="READ: DISABLED"`

I have a script that compares the `$line` variable against some patterns:

```
if [[ ${line} == *"RAW_READ_ERROR_RATE"* ]] || 
[[ ${line} == "READ\:"* ]] && 
[[ ${line} != *"READ: DISABLED"* ]]; then

devReadErr=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $8}')
```

Herein lies the problem.  The colon is screwing everything up.  I've tried every possible way of formatting the pattern to satisfy both possibilities of `line="1 RAW_READ_ERROR_RATE PO-R-- 100 100 016 - 0"` or `line="READ: 2513550726 22 0 2513550748 2513550748 27768.965 0"`  When I escape the : as shown above.  I can satisfy `line="1 RAW_READ_ERROR_RATE PO-R-- 100 100 016 - 0"` but not `line="READ: 2513550726 22 0 2513550748 2513550748 27768.965 0"`.  If I take away the escape, then I satisfy `line="READ: 2513550726 22 0 2513550748 2513550748 27768.965 0"`not `line="1 RAW_READ_ERROR_RATE PO-R-- 100 100 016 - 0"`

Sample Run 1:

```
line="1 RAW_READ_ERROR_RATE PO-R-- 100 100 016 - 0"

        if [[ ${line} == *"RAW_READ_ERROR_RATE"* ]] || 
           [[ ${line} == "READ\:"* ]] && 
           [[ ${line} != *"READ: DISABLED"* ]]; then

          devReadErr=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $8}')
        fi

echo $devReadErr
```

Output of Run 1:

```
0
```

Sample Run 2:

```
line="READ: 2513550726 22 0 2513550748 2513550748 27768.965 0"

        if [[ ${line} == *"RAW_READ_ERROR_RATE"* ]] || 
           [[ ${line} == "READ\:"* ]] && 
           [[ ${line} != *"READ: DISABLED"* ]]; then

          devReadErr=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $8}')
        fi

echo $devReadErr
```

Output of Run 2:

```
<null>
```

Sample Run 3:

```
line="READ: 2513550726 22 0 2513550748 2513550748 27768.965 0"

        if [[ ${line} == *"RAW_READ_ERROR_RATE"* ]] || 
           [[ ${line} == "READ:"* ]] && 
           [[ ${line} != *"READ: DISABLED"* ]]; then

          devReadErr=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $8}')
        fi

echo $devReadErr
```

Output of Run 3:

```
0
```

How do I get the best of both worlds?

Comment: These are all separate expressions; I don't see how changing one causes a different one to break. Can you [edit] in separate examples of *each* case that isn't working?

Comment: @AfroJoe : I don't see the usage of regular expressions in your post. Note that regular expressions in bash are tested using the `=~` operator, not `==` (which matches against file expansion),

Comment: @MichaelHomer EDITED: with sample runs.  (copy/paste and try yourself) :)

Comment: What's the problem with the third one? It matches the pattern `READ:*`, and prints the eighth field, which is `0`.

Comment: The problem is the program loops through all the possible values of `$line` (indicated above) and writes `$devReadErr` as `<null>` upon encountering `READ: 2513550726 22 0 2513550748 2513550748 27768.965 0` when the colon is escaped.

Comment: @AfroJoe, your third snipped doesn't have the backslash before the colon, so it should work to match the string as Kusalananda explained.

Answer (score 4):

You should remove the `\` in front of `:` in that second test, or it will try to match against a literal `\` character.

These are not regular expression matches you are doing, but shell globbing pattern matches (just as on the command line when you are using `*` in patterns).  This doesn't really matter in this case.

I'm assuming that you'd like to extract the 20 from the two first strings and store it in `devReadErr`, but not when the line reads `READ: DISABLED`.  This is exactly what your code does if the `\` is removed:

```
if  [[ ${line} == *"RAW_READ_ERROR_RATE"* ]] ||
    [[ ${line} == "READ:"* ]] &&
    [[ ${line} != *"READ: DISABLED"* ]]; then

    devReadErr=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}')

fi
```

Another way to do the same thing:

```
if [[ "$line" != *'DISABLED' ]]; then
    devReadErr=${line##* }
fi
```

This extracts the number as the string after the last space character in `$line` if the string does not end with the word `DISABLED`.  This avoids the `echo` and `awk`.

If this is part of a larger loop that parses a file line by line, then I would suggest writing it in `awk` or some other language designed to parse text.  See, e.g.,     [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716).

Comment: I edited the question with way more detail and sample runs.  As you indicated Kusalananda, its apart of a larger loop.  The use of awk is definitely an option, but I'd like to see if the collective can figure out the underlying behaviour of how BASH is working towards processing the expression.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want:

```
if [[ $line = *RAW_READ_ERROR_RATE* || 
      $line = READ:* && $line != *"READ: DISABLED"* ]]; then
```

The `&&` `[[...]]` operator has precedence over `||` but the `&&` **shell** operator has same precedence as `||`.

Or to make it explicit:

```
if [[ $line = *RAW_READ_ERROR_RATE* || 
      ($line = READ:* && $line != *"READ: DISABLED"*) ]]; then
```

Or using the `&&`/`||` shell operators and multiple `[[...]]`s:

```
if [[ $line = *RAW_READ_ERROR_RATE* ]] || { 
      [[ $line = READ:* ]] && [[ $line != *"READ: DISABLED"* ]]; }; then
```

Or change the order:

```
if [[ $line = READ:* ]] && [[ $line != *"READ: DISABLED"* ]] ||
   [[ $line = *RAW_READ_ERROR_RATE* ]]; then
```

Or use a pattern that matches all:

```
if [[ $line = @(*RAW_READ_ERROR_RATE*|!(!(*READ:*)|*READ:\ DISABLED*)) ]]; then
```

Without the parenthesis/braces, yours is read as:

```
if [[ ($line = *RAW_READ_ERROR_RATE* || 
     $line = READ:*) && $line != *"READ: DISABLED"* ]]; then
```

That shouldn't prevent it from matching lines that contain `RAW_READ_ERROR_RATE` though provided they don't contain `READ: DISABLED`.